# Jquery Click event working two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery Code is :

```
 $(document).on('click', '#showall', function (event) {
            $('#divcontent').animate({  'marginTop' : "-=25%"   });
            });
```

Purpose of this code is to show hidden content . This code works perfectly first time. In my application i using ajax . So after every ajax call **" margin-top : "** is increasing . For example after one ajax call **margin-top:52%** , second time **margin-top:76%**. Why the number increasing every ajax call. what i should do to make every time that margintop:25%

Comment: can you please provide a working example ? (e.g. jsFiddle)

Comment: 'marginTop' : "-25%" is working fine. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is increasing because you are decrementing it every time. `({  'marginTop' : "-=25%"   });`

That code should instead be: `({  'marginTop' : "-25%"   });`

Answer (score 1):

you can use some variable to check if the button was pressed before, something like:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#showall', function (event) {
        if ( !lockt ){
            $('#divcontent').animate({  'marginTop' : "-=25%"   });
            lockt = true;
        }
    });
```